# Background URL showing "checkout/cart" in Home page Magento 1.9.3

Tags: checkout, cart, magento1.9.3, home-page

When I am loading my website url 
https://www.logomatology.com/
 then I am seeing in background https://www.logomatology.com/checkout/cart
I have checked all files but I am not able to fix this issue?
Have any one idea? How to fix this issue?[image]

Comment: Can you check it in 1-column.phtml of your working theme. View-source shows the checkout/cart link top of the HTML.

Comment: Please check that page's view source or find `checkout/cart` in your source or current them. Maybe Ajax request overriding that URL with the page.

Comment: I have reviewed your website, Maybe some has added to `echo` or `print` checkout URL and forgot to remove it.

Comment: I have tried all these thing but not fount proper way